# What is a maven site repository in Nexus?

Tags: maven, nexus, artifacts

I am trying to find out what does each **repository format type** means when it comes to Nexus OSS supported repositories as I do want to store non Java things inside.

- maven2
- npn
- nuget
- rubygems
- site

Surprisingly the documentation says almost nothing about what they mean and what are the differences between them.

Comment: A site repository is more or less nothing else than a content repository which can serve the generate site from nexus without having to setup a supplemental web server etc. BTW: What do you mean by `each site type`?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/

Comment: Just choose `maven2` if you want to use Maven as your tool in the build process.  A Maven repo does **not** imply that is is for Java stuff. Think of it a *general repository for binary artifacts*. That's really the best definition of what it is. But, again, at the end of the day a Maven repo is really nothing more that a http server where the content is organized in a certain way. This means you do no really need Maven in order to access the content (we sometimes use simple command line `wget` to access our Maven repo).

Comment: thank you peterh, finally someone managed to say it: just use maven2 for generic binary repos.